# Expected: <false> Actual: <Closure: () => Future<bool>> in flutter unit testing

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-test

I'm writing unit tests to test the authorise function below which is in AuthService class.

```
  Future<bool> authorize() async {
 
    AuthorizationTokenResponse? authResult;

    try {
     
      authResult = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
            bsEnv.AD_CLIENT_ID!,
           ));

      if (authResult != null) {
        return true;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        forgetPassword();
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

I am using Mocktail to make the mocks. Below is one written test for the authorise function mentioned in the above code.

```
class MockBEnv extends Mock implements BEnv {}

class MockSharedPrefsService extends Mock implements SharedPrefsService {}

class MockFlutterAppAuth extends Mock implements FlutterAppAuth {}

class MockAuthorizationServiceConfiguration extends Mock
    implements AuthorizationServiceConfiguration {}

class MockAuthorizationTokenResponse extends Mock
    implements AuthorizationTokenResponse {}

class MockAuthorizationTokenRequest extends Mock
    implements AuthorizationTokenRequest {}

class MockTokenResponse extends Mock implements TokenResponse{}

class MockTokenRequest extends Mock implements TokenRequest{

}

void main() {
  late AuthService authService;
  late MockFlutterAppAuth mockFlutterAppAuth;
  late MockBEnv mockBEnv;
  late MockSharedPrefsService mockStorageService;
  late MockAuthorizationTokenResponse mockAuthorizationTokenResponse;
  late MockAuthorizationTokenRequest mockAuthorizationTokenRequest;
  
  const tUrl = 'https://endpoint/';
  const tUserImp = 'user';
  const tAppLan = 'sv-SE';
  const tClientId = 'client';
  const tIosUri = 'ios';
  const tTokenEndPoint = 'abcdeff';

  setUp(() {
    mockFlutterAppAuth = MockFlutterAppAuth();
    mockBEnv = MockBEnv();
    mockStorageService = MockSharedPrefsService();
    mockAuthorizationTokenRequest = MockAuthorizationTokenRequest();
    mockAuthorizationTokenResponse = MockAuthorizationTokenResponse();
    authService = AuthService(
        appAuth: mockFlutterAppAuth,
        bsEnv: mockBEnv,
        sharedPrefs: mockStorageService);
  });

  group('authorize', () {
    test(
        'should return true when the call to authorized method if result is not null',
        () async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => mockBEnv.AD_CLIENT_ID).thenAnswer((_) => tClientId);
      when(() => mockFlutterAppAuth
              .authorizeAndExchangeCode(mockAuthorizationTokenRequest))
          .thenAnswer((_)=> Future.value(mockAuthorizationTokenResponse));
      // Act
      final result =  authService.authorize;
      // Assert
      expect(() => result(), equals(false));
    });
  });
}
```

My test fails and below is the error message I get,

Expected: < false >

**Actual: <Closure: () => Future>**

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`authService.authorize` is an asynchronous method, returning a `Future<bool>`.
So your testcase should be

```
final result =  await authService.authorize();
expect(result, equals(false));
```

The await keyword leads to an async execution that resolves the Future into an actual value

Comment: **Then it gives the this error**  
    package:flutter_appauth/src/flutter_appauth.dart 5:39              MockFlutterAppAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode
package:/feature/auth/repository/auth_service.dart 51:34  AuthService.authorize
test/features/auth/repository/auth_service_test.dart 79:40         main.<fn>.<fn>
test/features/auth/repository/auth_service_test.dart 60:9          main.<fn>.<fn>

**type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AuthorizationTokenResponse?>'**

Comment: @Shashiwadana Presuming that `appAuth` is an instance of `MockFlutterAppAuth`, then the `appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(AuthorizationTokenRequest(bsEnv.AD_CLIENT_ID!))` call would match the `mockFlutterAppAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(mockAuthorizationTokenRequest)` stub only if `mockAuthorizationTokenRequest == AuthorizationTokenRequest(bsEnv.AD_CLIENT_ID!)`.